# "Enable Quick Website Search" saving websites while unchecked?

Tags: macos, safari, spotlight, search

### These are my search settings on MacOS Sierra, Safari 11.0x or Safari 11.1 Beta, no difference.

- "Enable Quick Website Search" is unchecked.
- "Include Safari Suggestions" is unchecked.
- "Include Safari Suggestions" is unchecked.
- "Spotlight Suggestions is unchecked.
- "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in
  Look up" is unchecked.

[image: My Search Safari settings]

[image: Spotlight settings]

Problem is that when I enable Quick Website Search and press "Manage Websites..." I see:

[image]

I erase and disable the option, come back later after using Safari, re-enable and more websites appear.

It seems like Safari always records websites with searches or something, and allows me to see it when I "enable" the option, quotes used here since option is always enabled.

How can I get this behaviour to stop, so that unchecking "Enable Quick Website Search" actually stops data collection?